# Issue With Contact Offset And Scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale, physics

Basically Setting Contact Offset In A Script Has Absolutely Zero Effect
I Set It For A Collider And Nothing Happens
However I Feel Like It's Something I'm Doing Wrong
Any Advice Or Fixes?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ColliderOffsetScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Collider thisCollider;
    
    void Start()
    {
        thisCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
    }
  
    void Update()
    {
        thisCollider.contactOffset = Physics.defaultContactOffset * transform.localScale.x;
    }
}
```

I Try This And It Does Not Seem To Change Whatsoever Even Though If I Log The Contact Offset From The Collider It Says Its The Right Size But Theres No Difference

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?